# php: Extra content at the end of the document

Tags: php, xml

i want to use this script so i can generate Xml files , first it worked well but i don't know why i couldnt use it then

```
require 'dbconfig.php';

$qr = 'SELECT * FROM pharmacie ';
$res = mysql_query($qr);
#res to array
while ($datas = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $result[] = array(
        'nom' => $datas['nom'],
        'prenom' => $datas['prenom'],
        'adresse' => $datas['adresse'],
        'type' => $datas['type'],
        'phone' => $datas['phone'],
        'fax' => $datas['Fax'],
        'email' => $datas['Email'],
       'ville' => $datas['Ville'],
        'region' => $datas['Region'],
    );
}
header("Content-Type:text/xml");

?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<people>
<?php foreach ($result as $v) : ?>
    <person> 
        <nom><? = $v['nom']; ?></nom>
        <prenom><? = $v['prenom']; ?></prenom>
        <adresse><? = $v['adresse']; ?></adresse>
         <typeph><? = $v['type']; ?></typeph>
         <phone><? = $v['phone']; ?></phone>
         <phone><? = $v['fax']; ?></phone>
         <email><? = $v['email']; ?></email>
          <region><? = $v['region']; ?></region>
        <ville><? = $v['ville']; ?></ville>
       </person>

   <?php endforeach; ?>
</people>
```

i had this message 
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

how can i repare it

Comment: Why first a while loop and then a foreach loop? Can't you just use the first while loop to create your XML elements?

Comment: Show us the XML it's outputting.

Comment: Try `echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` instead of just `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>` (PHP short tags might cause a problem).

Comment: @putvande He has a closing PHP tag right above that line ;)

Answer (score 0):

That's because PHP's short tags for open & echo have the following syntax

```
<?= 'print me' ?>
```

Your version (note the whitespace)

```
<? = 'print me' ?>
```